# What does spark actually encrypt?

Tags: apache-spark, security

I guess this is 2 related questions:

**Local Disk Encryption**

In the [documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/configuring-spark/content/configuring_spark_for_wire_encryption.html) it says

> Spark does not support encrypted data on local disk, such as intermediate data written to a local disk by an executor process when the data does not fit in memory.

Does this mean by default on-disk encryption is not supported but it can be enabled?  Because later on it says:

> 6. (Optional) If you want to enable optional on-disk block encryption, which applies to both shuffle and RDD blocks on disk, complete the following steps:

**Data In Transit**

Once again it says

> When encryption is enabled, Spark encrypts all data that is moved across nodes in a cluster on behalf of a job

But it also says

> Additionally, wire encryption is not supported for shuffle files, cached data, and other application files

So what kind of data is encrypted as it travels between the nodes?